# A list of CPUIDs?

Tags: cpu, x86

Is there a list somewhere of all known x86 CPU identifiers (such as „x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13”)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CPUID` is actually an instruction (ie a command/function/etc.) that Intel started building into their processors in the early 90’s (Pentiums and a few late-model 486’s). When called, it returns some information which as you mentioned, are combined to indicate the specific processor (and other data such as features), thus allowing a program to detect what kind of CPU is present (of course earlier CPUs can not be detected in this manner).

Because it is a CPU command, the obvious place to find a list is in the technical documents (programming specifications) of CPU vendors. There’s a gotcha however because after the Pentium, AMD split off and started creating their own CPU architecture which over time became less and less compatible with Intel’s (ie different sockets, different features, even different instruction sets to some degree). As such, you will also need to check AMD’s [tech-docs](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/ProcessorCoreEnumeration.aspx), lest you have incomplete information (after all, Intel has no motivation to include a competitor’s models in their [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.html)—in fact, the term ‘*AMD*’ does not even occur in it).

Another thing to note is that there are other CPU vendors in addition to just Intel and AMD (believe it or not, this is a big surprise to a lot of people). There are obsolete vendors like [Cyrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrix), some who no longer produce CPUs, and several others who produce CPUs for enterprise servers ([IBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)) or embedded devices ([ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)) and such instead of consumer equipment. If you want these as well, then you will need to research them individually because there is no central location to look (Wikipedia has [some information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID), but it is—not surprisingly—woefully incomplete), while [CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/CPUID.pl) has a lot more (go figure), though again, it is likely to be incomplete, especially since new CPUs are produced regularly.

Note also that many vendors do not include the `CPUID` command at all, so between that and the fact that even older Intel CPUs did not have it, technically, *no* list can be fully complete.

References:

- [AMD tech-doc](http://support.amd.com/us/Embedded_TechDocs/25481.pdf) ([search](http://search.amd.com/us/_layouts/search/search.aspx?csquery=cpuid&collection=support-us)).
- [Intel tech-doc](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/application-notes/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.pdf) ([search](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?keyword=cpuid)).

Comment: IBM no longer produces x86 cpus, ARM never produced them. The ‘other’ vendor you’re talking about is Via (and believe it or not, [x64 Windows will refuse to install on any processor other than Intel, AMD or Via](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/bugchecks/5d.htm))

Comment: @kinokijuf, I wasn’t talking about x86 anymore by that paragraph. I thought it was clear, but I covered the main x86 vendors in the first two and then explained about *miscellaneous* CPU vendors since some may include CPUID regardless of the architecture. And for the record, I never said IBM still produces [x86 CPUs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X2tPl.jpg), I clearly said that they only make server CPUs now.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#Uptake_of_CPUID_instructions_outside_x86), there are no other architectures (except for ia64) that include a CPUID equivalent.

Comment: @kinokijuf, *“The Intel-AMD x86 family has **so far** been the only CPU family to have a CPUID instruction. RISC, DSP and transputer like chip families have not taken up the instruction **in any noticeable way**, in spite of having (in relative terms) as many variations in design.”* In other words, anyone is free to implement such a command as desired. Like I said, things change *frequently*.

Answer (score 5):

Ask and you shall receive:  http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/CPUID.pl

While this page is not necessarily complete it does seem to have quite a large number of CPUIDs... here's a reasonably up to date example, the [i3 370 Mobile Processor](http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/CPUID.pl?CPUID=16114):

```
Vendor:                 GenuineIntel
Processor name (BIOS):  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz
Cores:                  2
Logical processors:     4
Processor type:         Original OEM Processor
CPUID signature:        20655
Family:                 6 (06h)
Model:                  37 (025h)
Stepping:               5 (05h)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another website that contains fairly recent list (till Nov 2014 the last time I check):

http://a4lg.com/tech/x86/database/x86-families-and-models.en.html

I wish this list can be updated again!